# From a long HTML to many JPEGs (or any other image)

Tags: javascript, html, image, jpeg

I have a long web page (vertically)
which can be thought of having 40 pages.

each page is divided by a hr element like this:

---

and has the same height: 860px.

I would like to transform each 'page' in that html in a jpg.
In an automated way of course.

Can somebody suggest how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an easy problem to solve because for one, different browsers may render the page slightly differently. So how important is it that the table looks *exactly* like it does on the webpage?

It's more common to *convert* HTML pages to PDF, for printing purposes or email attachments. There are many libraries to do this (but they're all a bit *meh*), I've used TCPDF with some success.

Answer (score 1):

You may either

- create an image of the whole page, then use some image library to split the `hr`s
- or inject some javascript into your page and use it to hide everything but one single page, then take a screenshot individually.

Try [wkhtmltoimage](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list), which uses a headless webkit browser to generate images of HTML pages. [Manual](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltoimage_0.10.0_rc2-doc.html)

Alternatively, there's browsershot's [screenshot factory](http://browsershots.org/documentation), which I haven't tried out but will probably do the job. However, it may require a bit of tweaking.

Then there's crazy things like [HTML parsers written in JS](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/), but I don't think they're any use in this case. Just to mention that.